# Nvidia GeForce driver for windows 8.1 not working on windows 10

Tags: driver, nvidia, windows-10

I have just recently installed Windows 10 and found that Nvidia has not came out with a specific driver for the 465 yet and was told to use the windows 8.1 driver as a workaround for Windows 10 and it still is not working it. I am getting this error in my device manager: Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)

Device PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_06C4&SUBSYS_083910DE&REV_A3\4&2534e90f&0&0010 requires further installation.

Is there anything I can do to make my driver work so I can use my graphics card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nVIDIA relased today a new Windows 10 driver, which supports your Geforce 465 GTX:

> Supported products: 
>   GeForce 400 Series: 
>   GeForce GTX 465

Download and install this driver.

**Download:**
32Bit: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/86509/en-us 
64Bit: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/86510/en-us